# Index on foreign key or on regular column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confused about where should I add indexing whether on a foreign key or on a regular column in order to make the database perform better?

the task is following:

> Find all of the bugs on software Debugger that pertain to the /main.html

here is my query for that

```
select t.ticketid, b.data
from bugs b
inner join tickets t on b.ticketid = t.ticketid
where t.title = '/main.html' and exists (
    select 1 
    from softwares s
    where s.softwareid = t.softwareid and s.url = 'http://debugger.com'
)
```

now, should I make it?

```
create nonclustered index IX_Tickets_SoftwareId
on [dbo].[Tickets] ([SoftwareId])
go
create nonclustered index IX_Bugs_TicketsId
on [dbo].[Bugs] ([TicketsId])
```

or

```
 create nonclustered index IX_tickets
 on [dbo].[tickets] ([ticketsid, title])
 go
 create nonclustered index IX_software
 on [dbo].[software] ([softwareid,url])
```

which one makes it more performant?

Comment: You add indexes on columns that are used to locate records in a query. Its a big subject, I highly recommend doing some reading on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select t.ticketid, b.data
from bugs b inner join
     tickets t
     on b.ticketid = t.ticketid
where t.title = '/main.html' and
      exists (select 1 
              from softwares s
              where s.softwareid = t.softwareid and
                    s.url = 'http://debugger.com'
             );
```

You want indexes on:

- `software(softwareid, url)` -- although this is unnecessary if `softwareid` is the primary key
- `tickets(title, ticketid)`
- `bugs(ticketid, data)`

The execution plan will scan the index for the tickets table, only for matches to the `title`.  For each row, it will lookup whether the corresponding software exists.

If it does, it will then look up the appropriate information in `bugs` using an index.

It is hard to think of a faster execution plan for the query.  The one exception is if there are many, many rows in `tickets` with the same title and very, very few that have the software you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Index on the foreign key is always a good idea. But your question is related to a specific query.

The index can make the DML operations slower too. so as mentioned in the comment, It is a big subject and you should read about the index before creating any index.

Still, a suggestion would be: As the `EXISTS` clause is used, I would recommend creating the index on `software.url`.

Apart from that, You can use the following query which may improve the performance.

```
select distinct t.ticketid, b.data
from bugs b
inner join tickets t on b.ticketid = t.ticketid
inner join softwares s on s.softwareid = t.softwareid
where t.title = '/main.html' and s.url = 'http://debugger.com'
```

Comment: Thank you. Should i tag (softwareid,url) so with id or just (url)? and what about tickets.title?

Comment: Softwareid is primary key so index is not required on it. Just go for url.